# Querying redshift via spark-redshift is not fast

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I connect to Redshift via pyspark using pyspark-redshift, i.e.

```
    sparkConf = SparkConf()
    sc = SparkContext(conf=sparkConf)
    sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId", 'AWS_KEY_ID')
    sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey", 'AWS_KEY')
    sql_context = SQLContext(sc)
    sql_context.getConf("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", u"5")

df = sql_context.read \
    .format("com.databricks.spark.redshift") \
    .option("url", "jdbc:redshift://example.redshift.amazonaws.com:5439/agcdb?user=user&password=pwd") \
    .option("dbtable", "table_name") \
    .option('forward_spark_s3_credentials',True) \
    .option("tempdir", "s3n://bucket") \
    .load()
```

When I compare the run time of a query, e.g. 300k rows on pyspark and Redshift directly I find no difference.

I read that the configuration **spark.sql.shuffle.partitions** should be changed to less than the default=200 depending on the size of the dataframe.

What are the important configurations I should check/ which people saw making a difference?

Comment: Please can you share information about the redshift query that you are running, the existing redshift timings and why you believe that running a redshift query through pyspark-redshift will be faster for your use case ?

Comment: Hi Jon, The query has 6 joins, returns about 300k rows and runs in ~20minutes on Redshift. Run via Spark it takes the same time. I tried decreasing the partitions `sql_context.getConf("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", u"10")` since the default 200 partitions might be overkill for 300k rows. Should the distributed execution not speed up the process?

Comment: What is the query you are executing?  As Redshift is a MPP database, for select queries there should be no benefit in parallelising in spark. Did you introduce spark to try to speed up the query? There are many factors to look at to improve the performance of a redshift query, distribution, sort, and the design of the sql all play a part. Also if you are returning 300k rows it may well be that the network bandwidth is also important! Need more information please update your question with the  necessary info.

Comment: Thanks for getting back. Yes, I'm exploring the option of moving ETL jobs to Spark using Spark SQL. After setting up the access to redshift, I trailed it with a query currently run by a scheduled job (just some user & offer level data for a certain time range). I agree that the query can be optimised in other ways of course. But in the end that's the idea of Spark: It decides the most optimal query schema.Hence, it seems that the actual extraction time would not be shortened by moving to Spark SQL.

Comment: I do see potential time savings after data extraction as post-processing may be faster in Spark SQL than in e.g. Python.